# Question on Coulomb force compared to Newton gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

I have recently started reading **Volume 1 of The Feynman Lectures on Physics. I am going through Chapter 2, Section 2-2 Physics before 1920.**

I came across this particular discussion within section 2-2:

> To give an idea of how much stronger electricity is than gravitation, consider two grains of sand, a millimeter across, thirty meters apart. If the force between them were not balanced, if everything attracted everything else instead of likes repelling, so that there were no cancellation, how much force would there be? There would be a force of three million tons between the two!

My question here is, how is the calculation of three million tons of force being arrived at?

Answer (score 0):

1. The mass of grain of sand is [$1.28 × 10^{−5} kg$](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/MarinaTheodoris.shtml)
2. Chemical formula of sand is [$SiO_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide#:%7E:text=Silicon%20dioxide%2C%20also%20known%20as,the%20major%20constituent%20of%20sand.)
3. Use that to get moles and number of molecules.
4. Now we can find sum of magnitude of all charges on each grain(since all charges are assumed to attract).
5. Use Coulomb's law after to get your value.

Compare that with the value of gravitational force obtained from Newton's Law if you want to see the difference in magnitudes.

Comment: the question doesn't ask for the gravitational force.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even to look at that why the electric force is so much stronger than the gravitational force.Since both forces are inversed square law forces:$F \propto \frac{1}{r^{2}}$ you can just compare $G$ and $k$.

Comment: It should be noted that you'd need to take some form of test masses/charges since G and k have different units and heir comparison isn't really meaningful otherwise.

Comment: @Triatticus just use natural units :shrug:

Comment: Sure you could but the idea is probably best to explain to someone who likely doesn't use those units since they aren't used extensively outside particle physics.

Comment: @Triatticus sure just put 1kg and 1C in the equation of the forces.